# Jquery large File problem with Google Chrome

Tags: jquery

I am working with Dreamweaver and Jquery mobile the latest version, my file is about 200k with a lot of repeated audio action, the file works well with Chrome when it is short, but the complete file crashes, and no problem with Firefox, Safari or IE9, any idea?
thank you.
Eric

Comment: 200kb HTML file? 200,000 LOC?

Comment: @Detect LOC is lines, right? Wouldn't this be ~200,000 characters?